# React bootstrap Button customization with a button name and a icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

**How to adjust the button height dynamically according to the button name?**

[image]

See, the name is cropped.
So far I have done as below:

**index.css**

```
.btn-product {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**index.js**

```
return (
    <div>
        <Button  target="_blank" className='btn-product' block  variant="secondary" href='/sign-up'>
            <span style={{position: 'absolute', width:'80%'}} >Button 1 with a long name</span>
            <BiChevronRight size={30} style={{color: 'orange',  float: 'right'}} />
        </Button>
        <Button  target="_blank" className='btn-product' block  variant="secondary" href='/login'>
            <span style={{position: 'absolute', width:'80%'}} >Button 2 with a long name</span>
            <BiChevronRight size={30} style={{color: 'orange',  float: 'right'}} />
        </Button>
    </div>
)
```

**The requirements are as bellow:**

1. button name should be left aligned
2. '>' icon should be right aligned
3. on button click, new browser tab open with the link.
4. button should be rounded like the image.
5. if name is too long, should not be croped, rather button height should be adjusted.

only number 5 is not done. Can you help me out? **how to adjust the button height dynamically?**

Comment: Could you share a simple sample of your code which have done in codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the display property to inline-flex and change the height to min-height
2. Remove absolute from the span and float from the Chevron
3. Add flex-flow: row nowrap, align-items: center as well as justify-content: space-between to the button.

```
.button { 
    display: inline-flex; 
    flex-flow: row nowrap; 
    min-height: 50px; // allows it to grow if the name is longer.
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly.
I just added some other properties in css to change the button view:
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 4px;
    text-align: left;